# xacro problem: Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]

Tags: ros, urdf, roslaunch, robot-description

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just like the topic I posed, when I try to use roslaunch command to run in the terminal, I met this problem (as followed):

```
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/xacro/xacro.py '/home/viki/ros_workspace/smartcar_description/urdf/smartcar.urdf.xacro'] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="$(arg urdf_file)" name="robot_description"/>
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem, I sincerely you could give the instructions about how to solve this problem.

Thanks so much for your time.

when I run the code `rosrun xacro xacro.py /home/viki/ros_workspace/smartcar_description/urdf/smartcar.urdf.xacro` to check the xacro, there is the information showed as followed:

```
Expat parsing error.  Check that:
 - Your XML is correctly formed
 - You have the xacro xmlns declaration: xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/xacro/xacro.py", line 35, in <module>
    xacro.main()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/xacro/src/xacro.py", line 542, in main
    doc = parse(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1920, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 928, in parse
    result = builder.parseFile(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 207, in parseFile
    parser.Parse(buffer, 0)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: junk after document element: line 197, column 0
```

Can you give me some information about how to solve the problem?

Thanks so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/122021/xacro-problem:-invalid-%3Cparam%3E-tag:-cannot-load-command-parameter-%5Brobot_description%5D/) by [saina110](https://answers.ros.org/users/11076/saina110/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2014-01-24

Post score: 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your xacro file (smartcar.urdf.xacro) is invalid; just run the command that's mentioned above from the command line and look at the error messages in the output:

```
rosrun xacro xacro.py /home/viki/ros_workspace/smartcar_description/urdf/smartcar.urdf.xacro
```

Once you've fixed your xacro file, everything should be fine.

If you can't find the bug, please update your question with a link to your xacro file (use the "edit" button).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2014-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saina110](https://answers.ros.org/users/11076/saina110/) on 2014-01-25**:
when I use the command you recommended, it showed like above( I added in my question), but I don't quite know how to fix it......how can I edit my xacro file?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2014-01-26**:\

1. Open the file in a text editor. 2. Go to line 197 (as the error message said) and figure out why it's not valid XML. 3. If you want more help, upload that file somewhere.

**Comment by [saina110](https://answers.ros.org/users/11076/saina110/) on 2014-01-27**:
thanks so much, I think I solved this problem, cause I didn't split my file into 3 parts...thanks again

**Comment by [Tahir Miriyev](https://answers.ros.org/users/31454/tahir-miriyev/) on 2017-08-06**:
can you tell please what do you mean by "split my file into 3 parts"? because I have the same problem and don't know how to modify lines of codes where errors occured.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might encounter such problems since you use a newer version of ROS. As far as I know, you should modify
the launch file's relevant part as

```
<param name="robot_description" command="rosrun xacro xacro --inorder        ...
```

---

Originally posted by [Ahmet Tıkna](https://answers.ros.org/users/68903/ahmet-t%C4%B1kna/) with karma: 31 on 2021-01-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ddudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/63947/ddudas/) on 2021-02-25**:
Great answer for Noetic users!
--inroder is the default behavior since Melodic, so it looks even more simple (if your model comes from the arg):

```
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro $(arg model)" />
```

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-25**:
For Noetic users looks `command` is not working either, so alternatively load file using file path. For example:

```
  <arg name="model" default="$(find pcl_tester_description)/urdf/depth_camera.urdf.xacro"/>
  
  <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(arg model)" />
```